# Android 14 - partial access to photos - how to show only "Allow all" option

Tags: android, android-permissions, user-permissions, android-storage, android-14

My app downloads pictures and saves them in **Download/MyAppName** folder. There is an `Activity` in the app that will scan the folder and get all the photos saved in there and show them in a `RecyclerView`. However the photos **will not show** in the phone's gallery app by default unless you open them by browsing the **Download** folder through a File Explorer app.
In that case, the photos that you open will show in the phone's gallery app.

The permissions the app asks in Android 13 and 14 is `Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES`

The problem is in Android 14 when the user does a "Clear Storage" from the settings or manually revokes the permissions.

So here is the scenario. You use the app and you download say 5 photos. If you revoke the `Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES` permission in Android 14, the next time you try to open the app it will ask to grant the permission. But, if the user chooses the option **Select photos and videos** it will show the photos that are visible to the gallery, which means the photos that were downloaded from the app and where saved in **Download/MyAppName** folder will not be shown.

So this situation is causing a problem because when the folder is scanned using `MediaStore` api it means the user will not be able to see the photos previously downloaded from the app unless he chooses **Allow all** when being asked for permissions.

Is there any way how to force the app only showing the option **Allow all** and removing **Select photos and videos** option, just like it is in Android 13?

**EDIT** (Answering the questions asked in the comments sections)

1. How the app downloads the files and saves them in **Download/MyAppName** ?

The app is using Glide to get the bitmap of the remote image. Having the bitmap it is then used to create the file in the given destination as in :
`bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, new FileOutputStream(destinationFile));`

2. Why the downloaded photos are not showing up in the Gallery?

Because the app is not using `MediaStore` api to create the file. You will have to browse the picture using a File Browser app and open them. Only after this is done then the photos will appear in the Gallery.

3. Why the app needs `Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES` permission?

Since the app is not relying on `MediaStore` api it needs this permission to even access even its own created files.

4. Why the user is seeing the option **Select photos and videos** in the permission requester dialog?

Because that's how [Android 14](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/partial-photo-video-access) behaves if you try to ask for `Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES`. In Android 13 and below it will show only the options of **Allow all** and **Don't allow**. When clicking on **Allow all** the system will grant permission for all the images saved in the external storage. This is same for Android 14 too but if the user clicks on **Select photos and videos** instead then the things will get complicated.

So, basically the original problem here is that the app is not using `MediaStore` to handle the creation of the photos. Even if we migrate to `MediaStore` now and do the things in the right way, still we would need a solution for backward compatibility. I was thinking that instead of asking user for `Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES` we ask for `Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` but not sure if the app will be accepted in Play Store because it doesn't really qualify in any of [these categories](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#all-files-access-google-play).

Comment: "My app downloads pictures and saves them in Download/MyAppName folder" -- perhaps you should change that to a location that is designed for media and is not restricted the way `Download/` is. Or, better yet, you could use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree` and let the user decide where on the user's device (or in the user's cloud storage) the user would like you to download the user's content.

Comment: @CommonsWare Even if I do that from now on, I will need to handle backwards compatibility :/

Comment: `My app downloads pictures and saves them in Download/MyAppName folder. ` You are not telling how exactly you do that.

Comment: `the photos will not show in the phone's gallery app by default ` Well you did not tell how they were created but often you have to let new files scanned by the media store. You did not tell what you do.

Comment: `The permissions the app asks in Android 13 and 14 is Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES` You do not need that permission to WRITE files. And also you do not need it to READ files the app created itself.

Comment: `If you revoke the Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES permission in Android 14, the next time you try to open the app it will ask to grant the permission` . Only if you programmed it to do so. But you did not tell us why you did.

Comment: `But, if the user chooses the option Select photos and videos` You did not tell us what you did to let the user see this.

Comment: In short: we dont know what you do. You should have posted all relevant code.

Comment: @blackapps Please check the EDIT section in the post

Comment: You took a lot of effort but all in vain as nice pieces of code are missing.

Comment: @blackapps I think all one need to know to give an answer is already there. Every other piece of code would be noise and irrelevant.